# SBT sub projects depending on each other

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project SBT build. There is a root which does not have anything, it just aggregates all sub projects.

```
lazy val aaRoot = (project in file(".")).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
).enablePlugins(PlayJava).aggregate(foo, bar)

lazy val foo: Project = (project in file("modules/foo")).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(bar)

lazy val bar = (project in file("modules/bar")).settings(commonSettings: _*).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(foo)
```

It is clearly a cyclic dependency here (`foo` depends on `bar` and `bar` depends on `foo`). What are the possible approaches to avoid these kinds of dependencies or is there an `SBT` way of handling this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the build tools I know allow for cyclic dependencies... and in my experience that is a symptom of a issue with the design of the application or modules, rather than a 'missing' feature from the tools. It's even seen as something bad when this happens at the package level in the same module/jar.

Can you merge those 2 modules? or reshufle the classes so the cyclic dependency disappears?

Comment: They are mostly independent except the entry points. Like `foo` needs to call a method of `bar` by passing one parameter of `foo` type. I will move them (both class and param) to another module called `core` or `root` and make that as dependent on both of the modules.

Answer (score 1):

As @Augusto suggested, I have re-organized my classes into three different sub-modules and using my Dependency Injection little more wisely. This solved my problem and gave much more abstraction than what I initially had.

Three sub-projects:

- api (Just interfaces)
- foo (depends on api)
- bar (depends on api)
- aaRoot (which aggregates all of the above)

In `FooModule` (in my case `Guice` module), I am binding `FooInterface` from api module to `FooImplementation` (foo module). While calling the bar module, I just use `BarInterface` (from api) by passing `FooInterface`.
Same as the case with `bar` module.

At runtime they all will be available and it can easily resolve.

Comment: :clap: for taking trouble to describe how you resolved your issue